# Can 'why' act as a relative pronoun?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns, relative-clauses

Please consider the following two main clauses.

> Both variables have the same range of values. Therefore, a 4:3 aspect ratio has been chosen.

I would like to combine these two main clauses into one sentence containing a main clause and a relative subclause like this:

> Both variables have the same range of values why a 4:3 aspect ratio has been chosen.

Is this grammatically correct? I could not find an authoritive answer on the web. While [this page](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/645/01/) mentions `why` as a relative pronoun, it does not give an example. In contrast, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun) does not mention it as relative pronoun at all.

If my second sentence is grammatically incorrect, could you suggest a way to rephrase it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second sentence is not grammatically correct. You could say

> Both variables have the same range of values, which is why a 4:3 aspect ratio has been chosen.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reason for its incorrectness?

Comment: Nope. I'm not a linguist, I'm a native speaker. All I know is that you don't use _why_ like that.

Comment: You can't use *why* as a relative pronoun.

Answer (score 3):

*Why* can be a relative pronoun after *the reason*.

E.g.:

> The reason why I am here is to help you.

In the example, *why I am here* is a relative clause modifying *reason*.